# Dragging and pressing buttons - Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, drag

I have several buttons and I would like to press on one of them and drag through another pressing them. Like swipe keyboard and want to get text from that button. How can i get the button text while i am dragging over them. I tried many method like manipulation gestures, toolkit gesture. Can you tell me the Exact way how can i do this. Thanks

Comment: here do you want to move buttons as you drag over other buttons or you just want same behaviour like in `SwipeKyeboard`.?

Comment: want the same behavior as swipe keyboard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want, can be achieved by few `EventHandlers` like `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave` & `MouseMove` etc. of each buttons..!

Check the code:

eg your button is:

```
    <Button Content="a"
            KeyDown="btn_keyDown" MouseEnter="btn_mouseEnter" 
            MouseMove="Button_MouseMove"/>
```

and your code behind is:

```
    private void Button_mouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Text += (sender as Button).Content as string;
    }
```

Hope that helps..!